# React Javascript - Copied object does not hold any changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently working on a project in which I have to maintain an object that contains an array of smaller objects (collections) in js. Adding and editing seem to be working fine but I have hit a snag when trying to remove from the the object.

```
removeCollection(collectionId, index){
    let copyCollectionItems = {...this.state.collectionItems};
    copyCollectionItems[collectionId].splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({ collectionItems: copyCollectionItems});
}
```

In the above code the object's state before the call looks something like:

```
{ 
collectionId-1: Array(4)[{...}, {...}, {...}, {...}],
collectionId-2: Array(2)[{...}, {...}],
collectionId-3: Array(1)[{...}]
}
```

Assuming the collectionId coming in is "collectionId-1", I expect the object to look like this after the call:

```
{ 
collectionId-1: Array(3)[{...}, {...}, {...}],
collectionId-2: Array(2)[{...}, {...}],
collectionId-3: Array(1)[{...}]
}
```

Instead I see that there are no changes to the object after the function call (collectionId-1 still has 4 objects in the array).

Is there something wrong with the way I am copying my object? Maybe the reference data is overwriting the new data? I have no idea why the object isn't changing.

I should also add that if the index coming in is 0, then the removal is successful. Any other index will not change the object.

Comment: You need to use a different array method. To remove an item from the end of an array, you use `Array.pop()`, and to remove an item from the beginning you use `Array.shift()`.

Comment: What about the cases where an item in the middle of the array should be removed? Doesn't splice cover that?

Comment: No, the middle would require splice. It would be better to use a linked list in this case, but that is a more complex data structure. I think the reason your current splice method does not work is because you're calling `splice` on `copyCollectionItems[collectionId]` instead of `copyCollectionItems[collectionId-1]`, as an example.